# How can i create a treeview control to be an options menu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a screenshot of what i mean options menu. This is the design i want it to look like but i didn't find any tutorials.

[image: TreeView Options Menu]

When i click the options toostripmenuitem i want the treeview options menu to show. But i have no idea how to create the treeview menu like the one in the screenshot.

```
private void optionsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode mainNode = new TreeNode();
        mainNode.Name = "mainNode";
        mainNode.Text = "Main";
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(mainNode);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very specific.  Are you having trouble building the TreeView?  Handling the click handlers?  Please [edit] your question to include more detail about where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

to do tis way use different panel for ur setting data design 
then use mousecickevent to display panel or hide the panel

```
private void tv_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   if(tvLeft.SelectedNode.Name.Equals("Genral")//Name of Setting
      {
        Panel1.Show();//keep other panel hide
        panal1.BringtoFront();
    }    
}
```